# How to mount static files using FastAPI and mangum?

Tags: css, python-3.x, fastapi, mangum

I am trying to deploy a static html site to aws lambda using FastAPI and Magnum. When running the application locally with uvicorn, the html page gets rendered correctly using the defined CSS style sheet.

However, the CSS file is not found when deploying the app to aws lambda. It seems that the static folder is not correctly mounted in that case.

Now, I was wondering how one can correctly mount static files when using `mangum`?

The `main.py` app containing the FastAPI app:

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from mangum import Mangum

app = FastAPI()
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory=path_static), name="static")

@router.get("/about/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def get_about(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("about.html", {"request": request})

handler = Mangum(app)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app="main:app", reload=True)
```

Content of the `about.html` where the `styles.css` file is linked

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', path='/styles.css')}}">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container"> 
        <h3>About</h3>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

When running with `uvicorn` the `about` endpoint is rendered correctly using the CSS style sheet:

```
INFO:     Started server process [67676]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     127.0.0.1:51247 - "GET /about/ HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
```

When running with the Mangum handler, the `styles.css` file is not found, and an error is returned (403):

```
2023-11-12 20:49:59,903 | Cleaning all decompressed code dirs                                                                                                                                              
2023-11-12 20:49:59 127.0.0.1 - - [12/Nov/2023 20:49:59] "GET /about/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2023-11-12 20:49:59 127.0.0.1 - - [12/Nov/2023 20:49:59] "GET /static/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 403 -
2023-11-12 20:50:00 127.0.0.1 - - [12/Nov/2023 20:50:00] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403
```